# Comparing two text files inside zip files using python

Tags: python, pathlib, python-zipfile

I want to compare two text files with same name and same relative path inside two different zip files using python.

I have been trying to search various ways and found none of the top solutions available work in my case.

My code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pathlib import Path

with ZipFile(zip_path1) as z1, ZipFile(zip_path2) as z2:
    file1_paths = [Path(filepath) for filepath in z1.namelist()]
    file12_paths = [Path(filepath) for filepath in z12.namelist()]
    cmn = list(set(file1_paths ).intersection(set(file12_paths )))
    common_files = [filepath for filepath in cmn if str(filepath).endswith(('.txt', '.sh'))]

    for f in common_files:
        with z1.open(f, 'r') as f1, z2.open(f, 'r') as f2:
            if f1.read() != f2.read(): # Also used io.TextIOWrapper(f1).read() here
                print('Difference found for {filepath}'.format(filepath=str(f))
```

Note:

I have used pathlib for the paths here. In the line `with z1.open(f, 'r')...` if I use pathlib paths instead of hardcoding the path, I am getting `<class 'KeyError'>: "There is no item named WindowsPath('SomeFolder/somefile.txt') in the archive"`.

Moreover, even if I hardcode the path, the file read buffer that is coming for comparison is always coming empty. So the comparison is not actually working in this case.

I am stuck in this curious case and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this without using `Path`, since the paths are specific to the zipfile and don't need to be treated in an os-specific way. The strings returned by `namelist()` can be used for both comparison and as arguments to `open()` as follows:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(zip_path1) as z1, ZipFile(zip_path2) as z2:
    common_files = [x for x in set(z1.namelist()).intersection(set(z2.namelist())) if x.endswith('.txt') or x.endswith('.sh')]
    # print(common_files)

    for f in common_files:
        with z1.open(f) as f1, z2.open(f) as f2:
            if f1.read() != f2.read():
                print('Difference found for {filepath}'.format(filepath=str(f)))
```

Comment: I'll try this, but for some other constraints I'm converting string returned from namelist() to Path variable. Does string typecasting, i.e. `str(WindowsPath())` convert path variable to usable strings again?

Comment: Thanks a lot. After a few tweaks to the paths, the solution worked. For anyone who needs this, the problem is that ZipFile.namelist() returns paths joined with forward slash (/), but paths returned from pathlib module and converting it back to string returns path with backward slash (\\), which return some funny-looking and erratic results. I took out the parts of the path and joined them with `/` to make it work, i.e. `'/'.join([*f.parts])` worked for me.

Comment: You might also have some success using `os.path.join` and `os.path.normpath` to deal with joining parts and ensuring compatability with the OS: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html